# Geocoder returns empty for only one address

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I'm using the `Geocoder` to retrieve lat and long coordinates from a list of addresses. It works perfect with all of them except for one, where it returns empty. I've tried the address on Google Maps (on device app as well as web browser) and it is a valid address, showing its exact location.

Any ideas of how to mitigate this?

This is the address that doesn't get processed: "315 Iron Horse Way, Ste. 101, Providence, RI 02908"

Comment: any more details ? like the address ?

Comment: @njzk2 added the address as well.

Comment: did you try variations around this address ?

Comment: Yes I did. Removed the suite number, removed the zip,...

Answer (score 1):

One option is to call the Geocoding Web Service directly.
It does return a valid response for that address, check for yourself:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=315%20Iron%20Horse%20Way,%20Ste.%20101,%20Providence,%20RI%2002908&sensor=false
```

Find more info [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/).

By the way, check also the [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits):

> Use of the Google Geocoding API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 geolocation requests per day. (User of Google Maps API for Business may perform up to 100,000 requests per day.)