# Android Geocoder just returns one address

Tags: android

I am using the following code to get a list of suggestions, if an user tries to lookup an address in my app:

```
String locationName = "Berli"
if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 5);
}
```

But it returns only "Berli, India" as a single entry in my list - instead of other possible addresses like "Berlin, Germany", etc. Same when I try many other places, just one suggestion is shown. Is this a correct behaviour of the Geocoder or should I use an other solution?

Many thanks,
Chris

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13310210/2700586

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like autocomplete would fit your needs better than geocoding.

Have a look at [Place Autocomplete in the Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#get_place_predictions_programmatically).